# Substitute for numpy broadcasting using scipy.sparse.csc_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have in my code the following expression:

```
a = (b / x[:, np.newaxis]).sum(axis=1)
```

where `b` is an ndarray of shape `(M, N)`, and `x` is an ndarray of shape `(M,)`. Now, `b` is actually sparse, so for memory efficiency I would like to substitute in a `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix` or `csr_matrix`. However, broadcasting in this way is not implemented (even though division or multiplication is guaranteed to maintain sparsity) (the entries of `x` are non-zero), and raises a `NotImplementedError`. Is there a `sparse` function I'm not aware of that would do what I want? (`dot()` would sum along the wrong axis.)

Comment: To be clear, you want element-wise division along axis 1? i.e., all `N` elements of `b[i,:]` are divided by `x[i]`?

Comment: Yep. "To be clear" is why I included code. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `b` is in CSC format, then `b.data` has the non-zero entries of `b`, and `b.indices` has the row index of each of the non-zero entries, so you can do your division as:

```
b.data /= np.take(x, b.indices)
```

It's hackier than Warren's elegant solution, but it will probably also be faster in most settings:

```
b = sps.rand(1000, 1000, density=0.01, format='csc')
x = np.random.rand(1000)

def row_divide_col_reduce(b, x):
    data = b.data.copy() / np.take(x, b.indices)
    ret = sps.csc_matrix((data, b.indices.copy(), b.indptr.copy()),
                         shape=b.shape)
    return ret.sum(axis=1)

def row_divide_col_reduce_bis(b, x):
    d = sps.spdiags(1.0/x, 0, len(x), len(x))
    return (d * b).sum(axis=1)

In [2]: %timeit row_divide_col_reduce(b, x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 210 us per loop

In [3]: %timeit row_divide_col_reduce_bis(b, x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 697 us per loop

In [4]: np.allclose(row_divide_col_reduce(b, x),
   ...:             row_divide_col_reduce_bis(b, x))
Out[4]: True
```

You can cut the time almost in half in the above example if you do the division in-place, i.e.:

```
def row_divide_col_reduce(b, x):
    b.data /= np.take(x, b.indices)
    return b.sum(axis=1)

In [2]: %timeit row_divide_col_reduce(b, x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 131 us per loop
```

Comment: Why did you choose `np.take(x, b.indices)` instead of `x[b.indices]`?

Comment: @askewchan It is often faster, and I was trying to get it to run as fast as possible.

Comment: Thanks Jaime! I knew that I could operate on `b.data` but I was missing conceptually the `np.take` call! Nice!

Answer (score 7):

To implement `a = (b / x[:, np.newaxis]).sum(axis=1)`, you can use `a = b.sum(axis=1).A1 / x`.  The `A1` attribute returns the 1D ndarray, so the result is a 1D ndarray, not a `matrix`.  This concise expression works because you are both scaling by `x` *and* summing along axis 1.  For example:

```
In [190]: b
Out[190]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [191]: b.A
Out[191]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  0.,  5.]])

In [192]: x
Out[192]: array([ 2.,  3.,  4.])

In [193]: b.sum(axis=1).A1 / x
Out[193]: array([ 1.5 ,  1.  ,  2.25])
```

More generally, if you want to scale the rows of a sparse matrix with a vector `x`, you could multiply `b` on the left with a sparse matrix containing `1.0/x` on the diagonal.  The function `scipy.sparse.spdiags` can be used to create such a matrix.  For example:

```
In [71]: from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix, spdiags

In [72]: b = csc_matrix([[1,0,2],[0,3,0],[4,0,5]], dtype=np.float64)

In [73]: b.A
Out[73]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  0.,  5.]])

In [74]: x = array([2., 3., 4.])

In [75]: d = spdiags(1.0/x, 0, len(x), len(x))

In [76]: d.A
Out[76]: 
array([[ 0.5       ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.25      ]])

In [77]: p = d * b

In [78]: p.A
Out[78]: 
array([[ 0.5 ,  0.  ,  1.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  1.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  0.  ,  1.25]])

In [79]: a = p.sum(axis=1)

In [80]: a
Out[80]: 
matrix([[ 1.5 ],
        [ 1.  ],
        [ 2.25]])
```

Comment: This works even for `M != N` as long as the diagonal matrix for `x` has shape `(M, M)`.

Comment: Thanks Warren! Sorry I picked Jaime's faster method... I was really torn between speed and elegance! Both methods are awesome and solve my problem exactly.

Note also that I misstated the question somewhat, and I also need to apply `xlogx()` to `b` before summing along the axis (0 log(0) is defined to equal 0), so I will need to operate on b.data anyway!

Comment: No worries, @Juan.  Jaime's answer is great.