# Numpy: Dot product with max instead of sum

Tags: python, numpy, max, sequence, dot-product

Is  there a way in numpy to do the following (or is there a general mathematical term for this):

Assume normal dot product:

```
M3[i,k] = sum_j(M1[i,j] * M2[j,k])
```

Now I would like to replace the sum by sum other operation, say the maximum:

```
M3[i,k] = max_j(M1[i,j] * M2[j,k])
```

As you can see it is completely parallel to the above, just we take `max` over all `j` and not the sum.

Other options could be `min`, `prod`, and whatever other operation that turns a sequence/set into a value.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Does anyone know if there is a special mathematical term for this kind of generalization? Perhaps the problem has been studied in terms of optimizations...

Comment: `dot` is a `sum of products` operation.  There's an `issue` request for a generalization of `np.einsum`, that would let the user specify both operations.  In Iverson's `APL` inner product is written as `A+.×B`, and other operators can be used inplace of `+` and `x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normal dot product would be (using numpy broadcasting)

`M3 = np.sum(M1[:, :, None] * M2[None, :, :], axis = 1)`

You can do the same thing with any function you want that has an `axis` keyword.

`M3 = np.max(M1[:, :, None] * M2[None, :, :], axis = 1)`

Comment: Or simply : `np.max(M1[...,None]*M2,axis=1)` and so on.

Comment: Would the first line of code be much slower than `np.dot(M1,M2)`?

Comment: @RadioControlled `np.dot` is a special case and AFAIK is not doing elementwise multiplication and summing, so yes  `np.dot` would be much faster.

Comment: Probably slower than `np.dot` as that is optimized and implemented in c-code.

Comment: Any ideas how to do this efficiently when M1 is a sparse Matrix and all values positive? So that only nonzero values are even considered...

Comment: You'd need to use scipy sparse matrices.  Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043299/substitute-for-numpy-broadcasting-using-scipy-sparse-csc-matrix) answer

Comment: Yeah, problems where that (a) only 2d matrices are allowed as sparse matrices in SciPy and (b) not sure if i.e. csr_matrix.max() ignores 'not exising' cells as it sais zero-entries are considered... But I'll read through your link first

Comment: Use [`scipy.sparse.find()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.find.html#scipy.sparse.find) to get rid of zero elements first.  The broadcasting issue is discussed in the answer I linked.

Comment: @DanielForsman: I really can't see how the solution in the link generalizes to two matrices... Are you sure this works?

Comment: No, but it's probably your best bet since sparse matrices don't broadcast normally.  That answer suggests using `np.take` to create a sparse broadcast implementation, which should be efficient, but it's hardly a complete answer for nD.  You might want to ask another question linking this one, which might get some of the more experienced folks (like Divakar above) to give their take on it

Comment: It should be noted that the main issue of this approach is its huge memory usage which is O(n^3) instead of O(n^2). It's speed is not much of an issue compared to this memory deficiency.