# SciPy - Generalization of dot product over sparse and dense matrix

Tags: python, numpy, max, sparse-matrix, dot-product

Assume normal dot product:

```
M3[i,k] = sum_j(M1[i,j] * M2[j,k])
```

Now I would like to replace the sum by sum other operation, say the maximum:

```
M3[i,k] = max_j(M1[i,j] * M2[j,k])
```

This question is parallel to [Numpy: Dot product with max instead of sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164305/numpy-dot-product-with-max-instead-of-sum)

Only now consider that the solutions

```
M3 = np.sum(M1[:,:,None]*M2[None,:,:], axis=1)
```

or

```
M3 = np.max(M1[:,:,None]*M2[None,:,:], axis=1)
```

should refer to a dense matrix `M1` and a sparse matrix `M2`. Unfortunately, 3d sparse matrices are not available in SciPy.

Basically, this would mean that in

```
M3[i,k] = max_j(M1[i,j] * M2[j,k])
```

we iterate only over `j` such that `M2[j,k]!=0`.

What is the most efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you looking to perform just dot product or `max` too?

Comment: Ultimately, `max`. I was hoping for a generalized solution where one can replace `sum` by `max`, `min` or whatever function. But `max` would be very important at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using one loop that iterated through the common axis of reduction -

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import scipy as sp

def reduce_after_multiply(M1, M2):
    # M1 : Nump array
    # M2 : Sparse matrix
    # Output : NumPy array

    # Get nonzero indices. Get start and stop indices representing 
    # intervaled indices along the axis of reduction containing 
    # the nonzero indices.
    r,c = sp.sparse.find(M2.T)[:2]
    IDs, start = np.unique(r,return_index=1)
    stop = np.append(start[1:], c.size)

    # Initialize output array and start loop for assigning values
    m, n = M1.shape[0], M2.shape[1]
    out = np.zeros((m,n))
    for iterID,i in enumerate(IDs):

        # Non zero indices for each col from M2. Use these to select 
        # M1's cols and M2's rows. Perform elementwise multiplication.
        idx = c[start[iterID]:stop[iterID]]
        mult = M1[:,idx]*M2.getcol(i).data

        # Use the inteneded ufunc along the second axis.
        out[:,i] = np.max(mult, axis=1) # Use any axis supported ufunc here
    return out
```

Sample run for verification -

```
In [248]: # Input data
     ...: M1 = np.random.rand(5,3)
     ...: M2 = csr_matrix(np.random.randint(0,3,(3,1000)))
     ...: 
     ...: # For variety, let's make one column as all zero. 
     ...: # This should result in corresponding col as all zeros as well.
     ...: M2[:,1] = 0
     ...: 

In [249]: # Verify
     ...: out1 = np.max(M1[:,:,None]*M2.toarray()[None,:,:], axis=1)

In [250]: np.allclose(out1, reduce_after_multiply(M1, M2))
Out[250]: True
```

---

Specifically for dot-product, we have a built-in dot method and as such is straight-forward with it. Thus, we can convert the first input which is dense array to a sparse matrix and then use sparse matrix's [`.dot` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.dot.html), like so -

```
csr_matrix(M1).dot(M2)
```

Let's verify this too -

```
In [252]: # Verify
     ...: out1 = np.sum(M1[:,:,None]*M2.toarray()[None,:,:], axis=1)

In [253]: out2 = csr_matrix(M1).dot(M2)

In [254]: np.allclose(out1, out2.toarray())
Out[254]: True
```

Comment: I'll have to read through this proposal carefully, but I have also implemented a version with a python loop. However, here I realized how incredibly slow python is compared to C...

Comment: It's not necessarily applicable here, but you might find this old answer of mine interesting.  It uses `as_strided` to iterate over the rows of a `csr` matrix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20062157/901925.  I forgot about it until someone just added a comment.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks! Striding on sparse matrices does sound like a new thing for me. So, surely worth a look!

Answer (score 2):

You could also check the `sparse` library, which extends `scipy.sparse` by providing a better numpy-like interface and n-dimensional arrays: https://github.com/pydata/sparse